# mat-checkbox keep selecting after updating firestore / reload page

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I am using mat-checkbox and ngFor to iterate an array from Firestore

By default the values of each `mat-checkbox` are disabled, that is, `false`. What I want is that when one or more boxes are checked and the page is updated, these boxes must keep the markup, that is, `true`. It's possible?

What happens is that I am making a total sum with each mat-checkbox and I want that any changes in the pages do not affect that sum.

My Array in Firestore looks like this:

```
paquetes: {
  paqueteId1: {
    ...
    extras: [
      {nombre: 'nombre1', isChecked: false, costo: 10},
      {nombre: 'nombre2', isChecked: false, costo: 20},
      {nombre: 'nombre3', isChecked: false, costo: 30}
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

**component.html**

```
<mat-checkbox *ngFor="let extra of paquete.extras" class="nmb" [(ngModel)]="extra.isChecked">
  {{ extra.costo}}
</mat-checkbox>

<span>{{total}}</span>
```

**component.ts**

```
get total() {
  return this.paquete.extras.filter(x => x.isChecked).reduce((a, b) => a + b.costo + 0, 0) * this.numeroPersonas + this.subtotal;
}

this.fs.getPaquete(this.idPaquete).subscribe( res => {
   this.paquete = res.data();
  }
);
```

Comment: you can change [(ngModel)]="extra.isChecked" to [ngModel]="extra.isChecked" . this will not detect change in component and your sum will not get affected

Comment: It didn't work, I'm sorry. Detect changes in the component.

Comment: can you show how your this.paquete array is look like.

Comment: You don't seem to write anything back to the database. You have to update the firestore database with the changes a user makes. If you don't update the database you will always load the same data from the database on a page reload.

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform some operations before assigning response data to **`paquete`** inside **`subscription`** of **`getPaquete`** function to keep checked values as it is. Do it as follows.

```
this.fs.getPaquete(this.idPaquete)
  .subscribe( (res: any) => {

    const paquete = res.data();
    const selected = this.paquete.extras.filter(x => x.isChecked);

    selected.forEach(y => {

      const found = paquete.extras.find(z => z.nombre === y.nombre);
      const index = paquete.extras.indexOf(found);

      if (index > -1) {
        paquete.extras[index].isChecked = true;
      }
    });
    this.paquete = paquete;
}
```

**Hope this will help you. Any queries are accepted.**

Comment: Sorry, I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'extras' of undefined` of the line: `const selected = this.package.extras.filter (x => x.isChecked);` when I try `const selected = package.extras.filter (x => x.isChecked);` everything remains the same.

Comment: it is not `package` it should be `paquete `

Comment: and one more thing make sure `res.data()` is giving data like your sample data array